# TypeError: table.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, http, fetch

I am simply trying to fetch data from a CSV file where I have to loop over an array of objects. But the loop is not happening and its throwing that array.map or array.forEach is not a function.
The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.1.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400">

    </canvas>
    <script>
 
        fetchData();
        async function fetchData(){
          try {
            const data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/');
            const table = await data.text();
            console.log(table);
            table.map(item => {
                console.log(item["Year"])
            });
            
          } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
          }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The backend node.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
var fs = require('fs').promises;
var parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
app.get('/',cors(), async (req, res) => {
  (async function () {
    const fileContent = await fs.readFile('test.csv');
    const records = parse(fileContent,{columns:true});
    res.send(records);
})();
});
app.listen('3000',() => console.log('listening on 3000'));
```

The fetched data looks like this:
[{"Year":"1880","Glob":"-.16","NHem":"-.27","SHem":"-.04","24N-90N":"-.35","24S-24N":"-.13","90S-24S":"-.01","64N-90N":"-.81","44N-64N":"-.46","24N-44N":"-.26","EQU-24N":"-.15","24S-EQU":"-.10","44S-24S":"-.03","64S-44S":".05","90S-64S":".65"},{"Year":"1881","Glob":"-.08","NHem":"-.17","SHem":".01","24N-90N":"-.33","24S-24N":".10","90S-24S":"-.06","64N-90N":"-.92","44N-64N":"-.43","24N-44N":"-.18","EQU-24N":".10","24S-EQU":".11","44S-24S":"-.05","64S-44S":"-.07","90S-64S":".58"},{"Year":"1882","Glob":"-.10","NHem":"-.20","SHem":"-.01","24N-90N":"-.29","24S-24N":"-.05","90S-24S":".02","64N-90N":"-1.42","44N-64N":"-.25","24N-44N":"-.12","EQU-24N":"-.05","24S-EQU":"-.05","44S-24S":".02","64S-44S":".04","90S-64S":".61"},.....(more objects)]

Comment: Do you have a mappable array returned from the promise ?

Comment: @SullivanTobias Yes I have attached the first segment of the array in the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `JSON.parse(table).map(...` . From the error it looks like table is not of type array.

Comment: Yes, it worked thank you very much, but why the map function was not working? It was an iterable array of objects so why was the parsing needed can you please explain?

Comment: the .text() does not return a mappable result

Comment: @SullivanTobias isn't an array a mappable object in JS? It clearly returns an array

Comment: Data in table was a json string not a json object and we don't have map or forEach method in string. Using parse we converted json string to json object. And as your json object of table is an array, so you can use all the function available in array object.            https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Incase you want to print or send a json object in string format, you can use JSON.stringify() method.

Comment: @PankajYadav Thanks a lot, it cleared my confusion around the idea of parsing data.

Answer (score 0):

```
const table = await data.text();
```

Is wrong

try with JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

backend is not sending the file as an object. try this

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const csvFilePath='./test.csv'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
 
const getData = async ()=>{
    const jsonArray= await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
    return jsonArray
}
// Async / await usage
app.get('/', async (req, res)=>{
    let data = await getData()
    return res.send(data)
 })

app.listen('3000',() => console.log('listening on 3000'));
```